# Redirect from HTML Silverlight Usercontrol to Silverlight Page

Tags: html, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am using Silver light application, inside that I build one Silverlight HTML usercontrol Where in I am redirecting one Aspx Page there are several control on that Aspx Page, when I Click on button in that Aspx page It should redirect to silverlight but , instead it's  redirecting to the silverlight HTMl COntrol itself..

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: it's working fine I have done like this..                           Window.top.location.href="/Default.aspx"